# How do I use Tasker to download web images and set them as my background?

Tags: tasker, wallpaper, live-wallpaper

I recently purchased Tasker after having it recommended to me by several people. I am trying to take an image from a website ([Unsplash Source](http://source.unsplash.com)) and set it as my background daily. As I am relatively new to using Tasker I tried looking for a tutorial on how to do this on but couldn't find one that worked for me. I found other examples that used different websites but have been unable to correctly adapt their instructions to fit the website I am using. I want to use this URL to download the picture from daily (https://source.unsplash.com/2560x1440/?nature/). Is there a way I can do this with Tasker? If so can you please show me how?

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just messed around with Tasker a little more and found an answer. For anyone who is curious here it is.
 1. Create a new profile set to every 24 hours.
 2. Add a new action
 3. Search for and select `HTTP Get`
 4. Set the `Server:Port` to `https://source.unsplash.com/2560x1440/?nature/`
 5. Set the `Mime Type` to `image/*`
 6. Set the `Output File` to `unsplash.jpg`
 7. Create a new action
 8. Search for and select `Set Wallpaper`
 9. Set the `Image` to `unsplash.jpg`
That should then change the background to a random image every day at midnight. Please let me know if I have made any mistakes, but from what I can see this works.

Comment: Looks good. It's good you posted you answer to help other users!